# How can I solve this definite integral ?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

[image]

How can I solve this? I need help with the steps

Comment: That second question is a bit awkward.  Still, do you know how to perform the substitution?  I assume you chose $u=\sin z$ for a reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second step seems an awkward way to proceed. But you can do the following to obtain $f(z)$

$$u = \sin z \implies du = \cos z \,dz \iff dz = \dfrac{du}{\cos z} = \sec z\, du$$

- So $f(z) = \dfrac {1}{\cos z} = \sec z$.

To find the new limits of integration,

- evaluate $u = \sin z$ at $z = \pi/2$ to find $b$, and
- evaluate $u = \sin z$ at $z = \pi/6$, to find the lower limit, $a$.

See if you can proceed from here, and if you get stuck, feel free to check back.

Answer (score 0):

$du =\cos{z} dz$ and $ dz=\frac{du}{\cos z}$, $f(z)= secz,g(u)= u^{-7},a=\frac{1}{2}, b=1$